# How to implement Spring microservice with eventuate tram without using docker and gradle?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, event-sourcing

I want  to implement a transaction based distributed microservice with eventuate tram framework without using docker and gradle, from the given example;

https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-sagas-examples-customers-and-orders

- Can I create the eventuate tram cdc as a springboot application?
- Then please provide me the steps.
- What should be the pom of the microservice.
- What extra properties that I have to add.

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: I have never asked for the code to be written for me, all I’m asking is the steps required to configure this.

Comment: Fair enough. It seems like a valid question.